# Linq to Objects: Distinct + Concatenation

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

I have a list of objects that where say 8 out of 9 of the properties repeat frequently with the last property being different throughout.

Using C# and LINQ to objects I'd like to retrieve a (grouped) distinct list of the first 8 properties with the 9th property concatenated across the group...

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int property1 {get;set;}
    public string property2 {get;set;}
    public string property3 {get;set;}
}
```

I may have a List such as:

```
var list1 = new List<myClass>
        {
            new myClass {property1 = 1, property2 = "foo", property3 = "This"},
            new myClass {property1 = 1, property2 = "foo", property3 = "is"},
            new myClass {property1 = 1, property2 = "foo", property3 = "a"},
            new myClass {property1 = 1, property2 = "foo", property3 = "test"},
            new myClass {property1 = 1, property2 = "foo", property3 = "value"},
            new myClass {property1 = 2, property2 = "bar", property3 = "Here's"},
            new myClass {property1 = 2, property2 = "bar", property3 = "a"},
            new myClass {property1 = 2, property2 = "bar", property3 = "second"}
        };
```

I am struggling to write the most performant LINQ expression that would produce the following list of objects:

```
{
    {property1 = 1, property2 = "foo", newProperty3 = "This is a test value"},
    {property1 = 2, property2 = "bar", newProperty3 = "Here's a second"}
};
```

Would anyone mind helping please?

Comment: what is your non-performant query?

Comment: Well so far I've been trying to work it out with a mixture of LINQ and a couple of foreach loops but there's a problem with that somewhere.  I've tried a few things now but haven't got all the code any more to post it - too much undo / redo...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are looking for is a [`GroupBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386922(v=vs.110).aspx) query with a composite key:

```
list1.GroupBy(x => new { x.property1, x.property2 })
     .Select(g => new 
                    { 
                      property1 = g.Key.property1, 
                      property2 = g.Key.property2, 
                      newProperty3 = string.Join(" ", g.Select(x => x.property3))
                    });
```

Comment: I had exactly the same answer :)